# Xamarin Forms Prism: prism A resource with the key 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage' is already present in the ResourceDictionary

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, prism, resourcedictionary

I have a Xamarin Forms 5.0 App using Prism 8. When I add the following into the ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type NavigationPage}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#ea5c2d" />
</Style>
```

I get an exception "A resource with the key 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage' is already present in the ResourceDictionary"

I haven't created a duplicate tag anywhere so am not sure why.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Maybe in this one  Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBackground}"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Look into your "App.xaml".

In my case there was a duplicate.